# How to totally consume bandwidth?

Tags: android, optimization, bandwidth

I have an issue in my current project.

I am currently making some `GET` requests to a restful API (and this works perfectly). But to be more user-friendly, I would like to optimize it in order to totally consume the bandwidth.

I tried to do it with threads with an `ExecutorService` which receives an `ArrayList` of `CustomRunnable` etc... using [this tutorial](http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-threads-concurrently-in-java-executorservice-approach/).
But it doesn't seems to work because I use a Network speed calculator app which shows peaks when I want it to be constant.

Is it possible to consume totally the bandwidth ? If yes, is my method ok?

Please ask if you need information.

Comment: "is it possible to consume totally the bandwidth" Please explain what you mean by this

Comment: why would you want to do such a dumb thing. why not try to conserve it.

Comment: I want to do this so the app will download much faster.